# Objectify annotations - asking for good, solid examples

Tags: google-app-engine, annotations, persistence, objectify

I got problem with JDO annotations in my App Engine project. I don't understand them. Thought that i can annotate something in my code, and it somehow works is black magic.
I got one simple Enity for Objectify which stores Towns names in one column and i don't know how to annotate them.

```
@Entity
public class Town {
    @Id
    int id;
    @Index
    String name;

    private Town() {
    }

    public Town(int id, String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And got error:

```
PM com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod
INFO: cause={0}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: At path 'id': Error registering com.jagienka.entities.Town
```

But main question: Could someone give some examples from a to z how to use JDO annotations?

Comment: Your question is confusing. You seem to be simultaneously asking about Objectify and JDO, but these are separate libraries which use different annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is caused by the fact that your `id` has the wrong type - `int` is not allowed. A field annotated with `@Id` can only be one of the following:

- `Long`
- `long`
- `String`

If it is of type `Long` then `Objectify` will automatically generate the id for you providing you haven't already i.e. not initialised. If it is a `String` or `long` then you always have to provide the value yourself.

As @stickfigure mentioned your question has nothing to do with JDO annotations since you're using Objectify. Change your id type to `Long` or `long` and the error disappears, like so:

```
@Id long id;
```

Answer (score 2):

GAE makes some use of the DataNucleus project under the covers, which has extensive coverage of ALL JDO (and JPA) annotations/XML. Obviously some may not apply to GAE where their datastore doesn't provide that feature.

http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/jdo/api.html

Comment: Ok thanks. Nice to have list of provided jdo features, but i think, for my purposes, I'll use not much of them.

Comment: Well your question says you wanted to know about JDO annotations, so that is what was answered. If you then "reveal" that you're using Objectify and will only accept an answer to that (different) question, it suggests that you need to make your questions clearer, otherwise you waste people's time

Comment: Hi @DataNucleus, I am facing such huge issue with JDO 3. That if i updated any entity then changes will not reflect immediately. If i retrieve entity after update then i am getting only old values. Updated change reflect after 30 mins to 24 hrs. Please can you let me know ASAP. I am in such terrific state.